# Are windows 8 apps supportable on windows 10?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1, windows-10

I am wondering if windows 8 apps will run on windows 10. I am considering to build an app on windows 8.1 but wondering if windows 10 user would be able to use it.

EDIT: And Vice versa are windows 10 apps supportable on windows 8.

Thanks.

Comment: I've been working on Win8.1 app for some time now, and it runs on Win10. You could easily test that when you build hello world app and see how it behaves on Win10. There are some concept issues though, for example the charms are not present in Win10 so they are transformed in a menu etc...

Answer (score 4):

Yes :) Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 will run on Windows 10.

But no, Windows 10 apps will not run on Windows 8 or 8.1.